# cygwin not working with grails interactive (windows)

Tags: grails

I can execute any command outside of the grails interactive mode, but when I try a command in it I have to wait forever (and nothing happens at the end), I don't have this problem with the MS native CMD and conEMU

Comment: Please provide more information. Which version of Grails are you running?

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'm using the latest version 3.1.5

Comment: and I'm using the latest version of cygwin, I think that the problem comes from cygwin and not grails since it works with the other cmd lines

Comment: So you can use the Grails interactive terminal in a native Windows environment and commands execute correctly - but when you run the interactive terminal in cygwin the terminal hangs?

I'm unfamiliar with cygwin but you may want to ensure your environment variables are set (and being read) correctly.

Comment: does cygwin have his own environment variables? because windows environment variables are already set

Comment: After doing some searching it seems that this has been an issue for quite some time. I can't seem to find any solution either.

Would it be possible to simply use the windows cli instead of cygwin?

Comment: Ok I think that I will stick to conEmu until I find a solution, thank you for your time :)